# Category Base permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I've noticed that WordPress (or Woocommerce, I'm not sure about who manage them) sets a default category base at "/blog" and I don't know how to remove it. Is there a way to do that?
[image: Category base]

Comment: Where is WordPress installed on your site? Is it in `/blog`?

Comment: Nope, it's in the root folder. For completeness, I'm working in localhost, even if I don't thing this is the problem.